# Promise logic in SQL queries to update subarray values

Tags: node.js, q, tedious

I have an application that takes an array of arrays and performs logic at startup to update the subarrays for later reuse. The subarray update function requires logic to check tables in two separate MSSQL databases, return data from one of them, and update some values based on the return. I'm pretty close, but I think my understanding of promise logic is just a bit off for what I am attempting. I'm using Q for promises and Tedious for the MSSQL library. Here's the code in question:

```
var machine_config = { database: 'machine' ...}
var pallet_config = { database: 'pallet' ... }

var hosts = [
  ['127.0.0.1', 'id', 'type'],
  ['127.0.0.2', 'id', 'type']
];

hosts.forEach(function(host, i) {
  var promise_machine = Select_Machine(host[0]).then(function(m_id) {
    console.log(m_id[0][0].value);
    if (m_id[0][0].value === undefined) {
      console.log("Not machine, maybe pallet?");
    } else {
      host[1] = m_id[0][0].value;
      host[2] = "Machine";
    }
  });
  var promise_pallet = Select_Pallet(host[0]).then(function(m_id_pal) {
    if (m_id_pal[0][0].value === undefined) {
      console.log("Machine ID not found!");
    } else {
      host[1] = m_id_pal[0][0].value;
      host[2] = "Pallet";
    }
  });
});

function Select_Machine(m_IPaddr) {
  var result = [];
  var deferred = q.defer(); // init promise
  var connection = new Connection(machine_config);
  connection.on('connect', function(err) {
      var request = new Request( // set up request structure
        'SELECT m_id FROM dbo.Machine WHERE m_IPaddr = @m_IPaddr;',
        function(err, rowCount) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err); // print error on console if anything happens
          }
          if (rowCount == "0") {
            console.log(m_IPaddr + " not found in Machines");
            result.push("0");
          }
          deferred.resolve(result); 
        });
      request.on('row', function(columns) 
        result.push(columns);
      });
      request.addParameter('m_IPaddr', TYPES.NVarChar, m_IPaddr);
      connection.execSql(request);
    }
  );
  return deferred.promise;
}

function Select_Pallet(m_IPaddr) {
  var result = [];
  var deferred = q.defer(); // init promise
  var connection = new Connection(pallet_config);
  connection.on('connect', function(err) {
      var request = new Request( // set up request structure
        'SELECT m_id FROM dbo.Machine WHERE m_IPaddr = @m_IPaddr;',
        function(err, rowCount) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err); // print error on console if anything happens
          }
          if (rowCount == "0") {
            console.log(m_IPaddr + " not found in Pallet");
            result.push("0");
          }
          deferred.resolve(result); 
        });
      request.on('row', function(columns) 
        result.push(columns);
      });
      request.addParameter('m_IPaddr', TYPES.NVarChar, m_IPaddr);
      connection.execSql(request);
    }
  );
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

The intended flow is to run through each subarray in the forEach statement, first checking the Machine database to see if any result is returned. There can be only 0 or 1 result, and if there is a result the 'id' placeholder for that host is replaced by the serial number corresponding to the IP address of the selected row. That works. If no results are returned, I'd like to check the pallet database and update the 'id' in the subarray. If no matches are found in either, we can leave the placeholder.

The behavior I observe is that if there is a match in the machine DB, the subarray value is updated and I can use it later. If there is only a match in pallet, the value never is updated. Is there something I could tweak in my promise queries or in my forEach function to make this more reliable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
hosts.forEach(function(host, i){
  var promise_machine = Select_Machine(host[0]).then(function(m_id) {
    if (m_id[0][0].value === undefined) {
      console.log("ID not defined, try pallet.");
      var promise_pallet = Select_Pallet(host[0]).then(function(m_id_pal) {
        if (m_id_pal[0][0].value === undefined) {
                 console.log("Machine ID not found!");
        }
        else {
          host[1] = m_id_pal[0][0].value;
          host[2] = "Pallet";
        }
    });
   }
   else {
     host[1] = m_id[0][0].value;
     host[2] = "Machine";
   }
    });
});
```

Seems to resolve the issue I was having.